# Synchronously verifyIdToken in Firebase java

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am building a Java server with rest API and I am using Firebase to authenticate my users.

When user make a reset call he sends Firebase token that I am verifying using the next method:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance(firebaseApp).verifyIdToken(idToken)
        .addOnSuccessListener(decodedToken -> {
            // do some thing
        });
```

The problem is that we are talking about HTTP calls, those are not synchronous. And while I found a workaround to make this method synchronous, I am curiosity if there is a native Firebase API that offer me that out of the box.

My work around:

```
final Object hack = new Object();
synchronized (hack) {
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance(firebaseApp).verifyIdToken(idToken)
            .addOnCompleteListener(decodedToken -> {
                // do some thing
                synchronized (hack){
                    hack.notifyAll();
                }
            });
    try {
        hack.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no simple way to make asynchronous synchronous. But it sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is the reason an asynchronous handler doesn't work for your use-case?

Comment: What is here exactly that needs to be done synchronously?

Comment: @cricket_007 I am getting a request from client, and since it's http I need to synchronously return a response. Before I can do that I need to validate client token. So I want the token validation to be synchronous

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I think you and cricket_007 ask the same question

Comment: Which happens first? Are you using HTTP with  Volley, or Retrofit, etc? Those are also asynchronous. But that doesn't prevent you from executing them within the Firebase callback, thereby making it synchronous

Comment: HTTP request handlers such as Express.js work fine with asynchronous systems like the Firebase token verification you're trying to use. Without seeing the real underlying problem, there's not a lot more we can say except what I already said in my first comment.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I work with vert.x in Java, and they don't seem to support asynchronous handling client response. But conceptually I don't understand why would want to use asynchronous systems in rest api, it is not by design. In websockets it make sense but not in rest... Most of the time I am serving static pages, I don't want to wast time on jumping between threads, my actions are minimal: verify token, serve the page. That's it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options (one is a example for spring):

1. You return a DeferredResult:

   ```
   final DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<String>> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<>(5000l);
   FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(firebaseAuthToken)
               .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseToken>() {
                   @Override
                   public void onSuccess(FirebaseToken decodedToken) {
                       deferredResult.setResult(decodedToken);
                   }
               });
   return deferredResult;
   ```
2. You force Firebase to wait for the returned token:

   ```
   try {
           FirebaseToken decodedToken = Tasks.await(
                   FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(firebaseAuthToken));
   } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
           log.error("Error: {}", e.getLocalizedMessage());
   }
   ```

Comment: Option 1 is not an option, option 2 is what I implemented, but I didn't knew they got native api for that, so nice!

Answer (score 2):

Firebase added this functionality in version 6.0.0.

Synchronous verifyToken method:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(firebaseAuthToken)
```

Async verifyToken method:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdTokenAsync(firebaseAuthToken)
```

According to the release notes:

- The Task interface was deprecated and is now removed.
- FirebaseAuth, FirebaseMessaging, and FirebaseInstanceId interfaces now expose a set of blocking methods. Each operation has blocking and asynchronous versions.

Release Notes: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/admin/java